# C Error: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, ubuntu-14.04, compiler-warnings

I was trying to learn some basic c code, to bolster my general skills. I wrote a basic script that tells me if a number is greater or less than 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   int number;

   printf("Enter an integer\n");

   scanf("%d",&number);

   printf("Integer entered by you is %d\n", number);

   if ( "%d" > 10)
      printf("%d is greater than 10.\n", number);
   else
      printf("%d is less than 10.\n", number);

   return 0;
}
```

And yet when I compile it, I get an error stating that I'm trying to compare a pointer and an integer:

```
dave@dave-[laptop]:~/Code/C/Examples$ gcc 004----takeandif.c -o 004----takeandif
004----takeandif.c: In function ‘main’:
004----takeandif.c:16:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
    if ( "%d" > 10)
              ^
```

And when I run it, it says that all numbers are less than 10:

```
dave@dave-[laptop]:~/Code/C/Examples$ ./004----takeandif
Enter an integer
2
Integer entered by you is 2
2 is greater than 10.
```

None of the other answers apply to my situation. What should I change?

Comment: `if ( "%d" > 10)` what do you think that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if ( "%d" > 10)
```

With

```
if( number > 10 )
```

Comment: And it now works fine. Thanks for your help, I was stuck on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that %d is just a placeholder, and since you want to compare the value of "number" to 10, you should write "if (number > 10)" instead of "if ("%d" > 10)"